# Dependency for installing MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

Let me ask.  libssl1.1 dependency is not installable for Ubuntu 2022.04. How CAn I install Mongo on this new release?

Answer (score 0):

Manually download and install the libssl1.1 package from Ubuntu 20.04 in Ubuntu 22.04.

```
sudo apt update
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed mongo6 on 22.10 (raspberrypi) with the help of [this link](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-install-mongodb-6-0-on-ubuntu-22-04/176976/6).

Looks for the comment from Chris Dellaway:

> As of 6.0.3 mongodb server is built for Ubuntu 22.04.
>
> The manual is yet to be updated but very similar to the 20.04 instructions but using jammy in the repo string instead of focal.
>
> `echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list`